# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError with embedded Jetty and Jersey (no GAE)

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jetty

I'm creating a REST API based on Jersey + Spring + Hibernate.
Everything works nicely when deployed.

I tried to add some integrations test using RestAssured which i want to be started from an embedded Jetty (mandatory spec) however it always gives this error (see below for a detailed stacktrace):

```
20-04-2013 | 19:14:43 | WARN  | (Slf4jLog.java:76) | failed jersey-servlet: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
20-04-2013 | 19:14:43 | WARN  | (Slf4jLog.java:76) | failed org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@192ffd75{/test-core,src/main/webapp}: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
20-04-2013 | 19:14:43 | ERROR | (Slf4jLog.java:87) | Error starting handlers
```

As the error says it is probably something to do with my SpringServlet, however i can't seem to resolve this problem.

My Pom:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.testing.system</groupId>
<artifactId>testing-core</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>testing-core</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey + Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring stuff, TODO: cleanup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Persistance ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <!-- will come with Hibernate core -->

    </dependency>

    <!-- Database drivers, etc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.60</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>bonecp</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- used for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.37</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.37</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.37</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spy driver used to provide a layer between the service/dao layer and the real jdbc driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>p6spy</groupId>
        <artifactId>p6spy</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Mocking -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Other -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring social -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--      <dependency>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
             <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
             <version>1.9.11</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
             <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
             <version>1.9.11</version>
         </dependency> -->

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>testing-core</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <system.properties>system_local.properties</system.properties>
            <database.properties>database_local.properties</database.properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <system.properties>system_dev.properties</system.properties>
            <database.properties>database_dev.properties</database.properties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is my web.xml:

```xml
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.testing.core.resources;com.testing.core.exceptions</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ResourceFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.testing.core.filters.SecureFilterFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Security filter -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Mapping of the rest URL /rest/* -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And finally the method of the Class (Class WithJetty that gets extended in a JUnit test) that will start my jetty server:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void startJetty() throws Exception {
    server = new Server(8070);

    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    context.setDescriptor("src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    context.setWar("src/main/webapp");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    context.setContextPath("/testing-core");

    server.setHandler(context);
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    server.start();
}
```

The actuall testcase is very basic:

```
public class UserResourceTest extends WithJetty {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertEquals(200, given().log().all().get(RSConstants.PATH_UNSECURED + "/test").getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

A more complete stacktrace

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:263)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:736)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at testutils.WithJetty.startJetty(WithJetty.java:52)
```

I have scoured the internet and stackoverflow for possible solutions, but all of them i found had something to do with GAE (which i am not using)

Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: I have made sure that my development JDK is java 7 too, sadly the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when tried to upgrade rest-assured from 1.7.2 to 1.8.0 or newer. So I  suggest downgrading to 1.7.2 as a workaround until better solution is provided.